pmatrix only considers one character before closing brackets
I am running Ubunutu 22.04.3 WSL2 with latexmk version 4.76. I had this bug when compiling with vimtex, so I tried compiling with latexmk directly and the same issue persisted. The compilation (with latexmk directly vimtex doesn't give errors) sometimes gives errors about luaotfload, but the output seemed fine. But for matrices it seems to escape after one character.
When I compile
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$$\begin{pmatrix} 01 \end{pmatrix}$$

\end{document}

then the pdf contains
(0)1

instead of the expected
(01)

When compiling
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$$\begin{pmatrix} {01} \end{pmatrix}$$

\end{document}

it does output the expected. Could this be an issue with luaotfload? As a few other things I tried (sections/greek symbols) didn't seem to have any issues and vimtex also didn't give an error I was not sure if this would be the issue, or something else. Also I had difficulty finding anybody else with the same issue, so not sure what would be the best course of action.

If you want to use the pmatrix environment, you should load the amsmath package. (and don't use $$...$$ for equations)

this error is unrelaetd to latexmk or vimtex, it's an error in the tex file so you would get the same error however you ran tex. It is an error in your  document not a bug in the system.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I didn't realize his was part of amsmath, sorry for the bad question (I am migrating from overleaf which gives an error in this case and I have a standard package with everything included). Also why shouldn't you use $$...$$ for equations?

@Sadim See Why is \[ … \] preferable to $$?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thank you!

The LaTeX kernel, for historical reasons, defines the command \pmatrix, that takes a single argument, borrowing it from plain TeX. The syntax would be
\pmatrix{1 & 0 \cr 0 & 1}

The idea, at the time LaTeX was being developed, was that having similar commands to plain TeX would ease the adoption.
In AMS-TeX, instead, there was the construction \pmatrix ... \endpmatrix and using the plain syntax would lead to low level errors. The syntax had to be
\pmatrix 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \endpmatrix

When AMS-TeX was ported to LaTeX, the syntax switch was obvious: instead of the above, when amsmath is loaded (it used to be called amslatex in the first years, though)
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}

However, amsmath introduces a safeguard against usage according to the older syntax. One should be aware that doing \begin{pmatrix} eventually executes \pmatrix.
Thus amsmath defines \pmatrix to check if the current environment name is pmatrix, that is, \pmatrix is called as a consequence of \begin{pmatrix}. If it is, it assumes “new syntax”, otherwise it uses the plain TeX syntax.
But if you don't load amsmath, there is just the kernel definition of \pmatrix and \endpmatrix (which is executed by \end{pmatrix}) just closes the group initiated by \begin{pmatrix}.
This is where your code “fails”: the kernel \pmatrix absorbs an argument and in your case, where there are no braces, the argument is just 0. So what you get is the same as
\begingroup\pmatrix{0}1\endgroup

and you get (0)1.
The way out is easy: always load amsmath if your document has more than very simple formulas.
By the way, $$ should never be used inside a LaTeX document environment. No excuses. See Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?

Not sure why this was closed as off topic, I voted to re-open

As @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz and @David Carlisle said in the comments this issue is with my code not the compiler, matrices are part of amsmath, but an error is not thrown by latexmk for missing this package.

You get no error as latex has a \pmatrix command (not environment) inherited from plain tex so \begin{pmatrix} 0  is \pmatrix{0} which makes a 1x1 matrix 0
